# Best way to replace Static Variables in the classes

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have classes which are using controller variables.

This is my HomeController which has variables such as

```
.....
        public static String Origin = "no";
        public static String Destination = "";
        public static String startTime = "";
.....
```

And i am using these variables in the CSVReader class for example as

```
.....
         HomeController.Origin = str[0].ToString();
         HomeController.Destination = str[1].ToString();
         HomeController.startTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str[5].ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'), 
.....
```

This works fine for the HomeController but now i need to add another Controller with 90% of the same logic but i am confused what is the best way to replace variables in my classes because right now i am using HomeController.Origin variable in CSVReader but with the new Controller i want my CSVReader variables be like e.g `HomeController2.Origin, HomeController2.Destination,HomeController2.startTime etc`

I have tried to explain my problem in the simplest way :). What is the best way to make it done??

Comment: Then create a collection like `HomeController[]` and don't make it `static` at all. Or use collections as fields like `static String[] Origins`.

Comment: These are clearly instance variables.  They shouldn't be static at all.  In fact, they should probably be encapsulated inside of reader implementation class

Comment: or should i change the CSVReader method from void to array of Strings returning and then used it in the Controller class?

Comment: I'd do as @DavidL says and go with a separate class for the reader, or at least a method that returns what you want. This is not a good use for class variables.